# How can I fix the Excel ghost/phantom tab glitch?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a large Excel spreadsheet full of VBA macros, but I keep running into the infamous Excel glitch that shows a ghost image of one tab on top of the currently selected tab. Has anybody else seen this? Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Do you use `.Select` or `.Activate` in your code?  If so, don't. There are very very few reasons to do so.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: I do use both. Do you think that is causing my problem?

Comment: Yes I do think that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: It is also slowing your code, and making it harder to read.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I will take a look at this.